# Get all tweets,all following and all followers from 2015-12-01 to 2016-03-20 using twitter api

Tags: twitter

i want to get all tweets,all followers and all followings from 2015-12-01 to 2016-03-20 using twitter api.
when i use following code it always give me latest 20 tweet,i am passing the 'until' parameter to get all tweets but i want to pass date such as "from 2015-12-01 to 2016-03-20".
how is this possible to get twitter data from 2015-12-01 to 2016-03-20.

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

$twtrdata = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=" . $twitteruser . "&until:2016-03-01");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `until`-parameter for the Twitter API `user_timeline`.

The Twitter API is pretty limited, for example, using `user_timeline` will only return a maximum of 200 tweets at a time, and you will have to call it multiple times to get all tweets. There is a `created_at`-attribute connected to the tweets returned that you can use to filter out the tweets you want within a time frame, but you'll still have to run multiple requests to get all of them, probably. In addition to the 200 per request limit, there is also a restriction in place so that you cannot fetch more than the 3200 most recent tweets of a user.

For more info on this API call, and the rest of the Twitter API, have a look at Twitter's [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline).

Comment: if i want to get tweets till 2016-03-20, then how it will possible for me to get tweets ????

Comment: You will have to get the tweets multiple times and filter out the ones you want yourself. Use the ID of the last tweet returned and set the `max_id`-parameter to get the rest of the tweets.